# database query cuts the end of a long text

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query like this:

```
    $sql = "select qu.id as qu_id, qu.question_id as qu_question_id, qu.question_time as qu_question_time, qu.time as qu_time, qu.useruid as q_useruid, qu.originuid as qu_originuid, concat(concat(' ', GROUP_CONCAT(follow.followeruid SEPARATOR ' ')), ' ') as f_followers, concat(concat(' ', GROUP_CONCAT(feeds.user_id SEPARATOR ' ')), ' ') as f_user_id
            from (select question_updates.id, question_updates.question_id, question_updates.question_time, question_updates.time, questions.originuid, questions.useruid, questions.id as qu_id
                  from question_updates
              join questions
                  on question_updates.question_id = questions.id
                  limit 0, %i) qu
            left join follow
            on follow.useruid = qu.useruid
            left join feeds
            on feeds.question_id = qu_id and (follow.followeruid = feeds.user_id or qu.originuid = feeds.user_id or qu.useruid = feeds.user_id)
            group by qu_id;";
    $elements = App::db()->query($sql, $limit);
```

This is executed by `flourishlib`. My problem is that the value of

f_followers

contains only a part of the actual result.

I have echoed its value, but the result was:

> string(1026) "410187 410187 413087 413087 415151 415151 417290 417290
>   433722 433722 404603 404603 507657 507657 453264 453264 568415 568415
>   467570 467570 552061 552061 568842 568842 568842 568842 568842 568842
>   566207 566207 413241 413241 563720 563720 599200 599200 420944 420944
>   489667 489667 607203 607203 628892 628892 548470 548470 628001 628001
>   485418 485418 693679 693679 446736 446736 628922 628922 704588 704588
>   711213 711213 705814 705814 726077 726077 701705 701705 733424 733424
>   711319 711319 571667 571667 432333 432333 626145 626145 654618 654618
>   612619 612619 750817 750817 568955 568955 621153 621153 565888 565888
>   626355 626355 798923 798923 808107 808107 808107 808107 417740 417740
>   809480 809480 642222 642222 807336 807336 402777 402777 811486 811486
>   644565 644565 645200 645200 761810 761810 820679 820679 456459 456459
>   823283 823283 595438 595438 826692 826692 828011 828011 761635 761635
>   618987 618987 828800 828800 765090 765090 838269 838269 698528 698528
>   791219 791219 728155 728155 465008 465008 866256 866256 45"

where 45 is not an actual value, it is actually a part of the value of 452989.

This leads to a huge bug. My question is: is there a MySQL/flourishlib limitation for text length in the returning value set? Is there a way to tell MySQL/flourishlib to not cut the end of the

```
GROUP_CONCAT(follow.followeruid SEPARATOR ' ')), ' ') as f_followers
```

value?

EDIT: As the answer shows, this problem is not related to flourishlib, it is a database setting.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, can you add that as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are bumping against the default length limit for `GROUP_CONCAT()` which is merely 1024 characters. [The `group_concat_max_len` system variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) is available for you to increase the limit.  Determine what a sensible maximum would be for your application's needs and set the variable for the current session.

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 65536
```

No modifications to your code are then necessary.

Comment: I have modified it to 100 000, because group_concat is wisely used and we might even surpass this. This is a cron job. Thanks again, you were pointing me to the right direction.